# A simplest way to convert array to 2d array in scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I have a 10 × 10 `Array[Int]`

```
val matrix = for {
    r <- 0 until 10
    c <- 0 until 10
} yield r + c
```

and want to convert the "matrix" to an `Array[Array[Int]]` with 10 rows and 10 columns.

What is the simplest way to do it?

Comment: `matrix`, as you've defined it, is a `Vector[Int]`, not an `Array[Int]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
val matrix = (for {
    r <- 0 until 3
    c <- 0 until 3
} yield r + c).toArray
// Array(0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4)

scala> matrix.grouped(3).toArray
// Array(Array(0, 1, 2), Array(1, 2, 3), Array(2, 3, 4))
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand correctly, you can do :

```
Array.tabulate(10,10)(_+_)               
//> res0: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9), ....)
```

If you just need a 10 x 10 Array[Int] without any values you can do,

```
Array.ofDim[Int](10,10)

/> res1: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0
                                              //| , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Array(0, ....
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you showed gives you a Vector of Int, not an Array. If Vector and it is okay to generate a new you just need to yield twice

```
val matrix = for (r <- 1 to 10)
  yield for(c <- 1 to 10)
    yield r+c
```

If you need to convert the existing Vector to Array[Array[Int]] as you said, use grouped as chris-martin suggested

```
matrix.grouped(10).toArray.map(_.toArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (x <- (0 until 10).toArray) yield (x until x + 10).toArray
```